# Spring 4 websockets dynamic MessageMapping not executed

Tags: spring, sockjs, spring-websocket

I'm using Spring 4 websockets on Tomcat 8 and I have the following configuration:

```xml
<websocket:message-broker application-destination-prefix="/app">
    <websocket:stomp-endpoint path="/notify">
        <websocket:sockjs />
    </websocket:stomp-endpoint>
    <websocket:simple-broker prefix="/topic" />
</websocket:message-broker>
```

My Spring controller has the following method:

```java
@MessageMapping("/notify/{client}")
public void pushMessage(@DestinationVariable long client, String message) {
    System.out.println("Send " + message + " to " + client);
    template.convertAndSend("/topic/push/" + client, message);
}
```

So what I'm trying to do here is that if client 1 wants to send a message to client 2, he uses `/app/notify/2`. The Spring controller will then push the message to topic `/topic/push/2`.

I wrote the following code in my client:

```js
var id = 1;
var sock = new SockJS('/project/notify');
var client = Stomp.over(sock);
client.connect({}, function() {
    client.subscribe('/topic/push/' + id, function(message) {
        console.log(message);
    });
});
```

The connection works perfectly, `/project` is just the context root of my application.

I also have the following code in my client to send a message:

```js
client.send('/app/notify/' + id, {}, "test");
```

Both variables (`client` and `id`) are accessible, I'm not getting any errors from this part of the code and I can see in my console that the message is actually sent:

```
>>> SEND
destination:/app/notify/1
content-length:4

test
```

However, the `System.out.println()` statement in my controller is never executed, so I assume there is something wrong with my controller mappings or I'm not using the destination endpoints correctly (I don't understand why I have to specify the application prefix here, but not when connecting to that endpoint).

Comment: I am working on implementing group chat and following similar approach i.e. publish the message to a topic with unique **groupId** on the server and on the client side, subscribe to that topic using group id. This approach is working fine when I am using **Simple Broker** but fails when I use **External Broker(RabbitMQ)**. It says "invalid destination" in that case. Do you have any idea of this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems it's unable to map when using a simple `String` message as payload. When I wrap the `message` in an object, then it works just fine.

EDIT: As stated in the comments, Spring already comes with a message wrapper called the [`TextMessage`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/socket/TextMessage.html) class.

Comment: You can use the TextMessage type object to send your string, since you are using STOMP.

Comment: I'm using the SimpMessagingTemplate, that accept a org.springframework.messaging.Message but the TextMessage inherit from org.springframework.web.socket... how can send a simple STOMP string not converted in a JSON object?

Comment: can you please explain a bit deeper, what do you mean by `in an object`, I tried something similar but didn't worked.

Comment: @coding_idiot write a class with a string field and use that class as the payload. Or use `TextMessage` like @AliR mentioned.

Comment: did that, didn't worked... looks like a dependency collision issue.